# What types of derivatives, other than stock options, are available to the retail trader?

Tags: trading, options, futures, derivatives, commodities

How can a retail trader identify other derivative instruments to trade, and how can one go about doing so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Other derivatives include warrants which are equivalent to a very long term option, futures contracts  and  single stock futures.  Outside the US there are CFDs (Contract for Difference).

Comment: Thanks, perhaps the question I should've asked then is what kinds of futures are available to the retail trader (oil, pork, soy, gold, etc.)? And how does a retail trader trade them?

Comment: To find out the kinds of futures that are available to the retail trader, Google: "Futures Market Symbol List".  To trade them, you need an account at with a futures broker. I traded some 30+ years ago and quickly realized that they were not for me so I really don't have anything more than that Captain Obvious information to offer you.